# Reindex a single product

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

My magento store has products around 30000.

Everytime When i upload/update new product, i have to reindex the whole store which takes very huge time.

So basically i would like to have a php script or any method which reindex all the indexes of a particular single product.

Is there any defined script/method to achieve?? please help.

Comment: @userpk colud you please explain how that script could be used for reindexing my choice of product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Guruprasad as per answer from @Vinai

You can simply pass the product object and process the selected event for single product

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('1'); // Product Id

$event = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->logEvent(
        $product,
        $product->getResource()->getType(),
        Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE,
        false
    );
    Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')
        ->getProcessByCode('catalog_url') // Adjust the indexer process code as needed
        ->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)
        ->processEvent($event);
```

Comment: so do i have to run this script as a php file?

Comment: This depends on you. You can run via observer on product save after and place this code. Or if you want to run as cron. What ever your requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

Login in admin  panel

Go to `System->Index Management`

click on `Select all`

click `Actions` dropdown and set `Change Index Mode`

the other dropdown will appears and set `Update on Save` in other dropdown.

and click on submit button.

Comment: i asked for a solution where in i want solution for reindexing a single product, your solution will apply for all products.

Comment: @Guruprasad, when you set this settings index fires on save

Comment: i know that would trigger reindex on save. But my requirement is not  to generalize that to all products. I just want a single product to reindex of my required